# VMWare Virtual Machine Monitor Failed in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: vmware-workstation

I can't run vmware 12 in my ubuntu 16.04 LTS OS. It always show vitual machine monitor failed.

[image: Here's the screenshot]

Comment: and what is output of following log file?

Comment: Solved for Ubuntu 19: http://rglinuxtech.com/?p=2522#comment-55900 https://gist.github.com/PiN73/7a890b21f2d2dd22bdc0219b0eebc00e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem.

Ubuntu 16.04, VMware Workstation 12.1.0 build-3272444

1. Disable Secure Boot in my BIOS.
2. Run

   ```
   sudo su -      
   vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
   ```

Comment: Is there a way to fix this problem with secure boot enabled?

Comment: Disabling secure boot did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Using Charly's script on [superuser.com/questions/1328401/vmware-workstation-vmmon-broken-on-ubuntu-18-04/](http://superuser.com/questions/1328401/vmware-workstation-vmmon-broken-on-ubuntu-18-04/), I was able to build the needed modules for kernel 4.15.0-29-generic on 16.04LTS. There is a typo at the end of the script, there should not be a line return between `sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1` and `/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libz.so.1/libz.so.1`

Another addition I would recommend is to add `sudo /etc/init.d/vmware restart` command to the end of the above script.

So the actual solution script with tweaks is:

```
#!/bin/bash
VMWARE_VERSION=workstation-12.5.9
TMP_FOLDER=/tmp/patch-vmware
rm -fdr $TMP_FOLDER
mkdir -p $TMP_FOLDER
cd $TMP_FOLDER
git clone https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules.git
cd $TMP_FOLDER/vmware-host-modules
git checkout $VMWARE_VERSION
git fetch
make
sudo make install
sudo rm /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libz.so.1/libz.so.1
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libz.so.1/libz.so.1
sudo /etc/init.d/vmware restart
```

```

Sorry this isn't a comment on Charly's answer, I don't have the reputation on this account.

Note that this will only work for `Workstation 12.5.9`, you can easily tell which version you have by running `vmware --version`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution was using `vmware-workstation-version-12.1.1-3770994`. I tried it and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm running Workstation 16.0 on Ubuntu 20.10, and I needed to enroll MOK keys using `MOKutil` before `vmware-modconfig` would complete successfully.

There's a comprehensive guide here: https://develmonk.com/2020/06/06/whats-wrong-with-vmware-workstation-on-ubuntu/