# VMware 12.1 software installation error in Ubuntu 16.04 - Several Modules must be complied and loaded into kernel

Tags: 16.04, vmware-workstation

Actual error in log is below.

**Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.**

I've tried the below solutions already. But nothing worked out well.
[Vmware kernel module error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791611/vmware-kernel-module-error)
[VMWare Workstation Pro 12 on Ubuntu 16.04 cannot compile vmmon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812552/vmware-workstation-pro-12-on-ubuntu-16-04-cannot-compile-vmmon)      https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7841306.html#7841306    [VMWare Virtual Machine Monitor Failed in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767791/vmware-virtual-machine-monitor-failed-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

Comment: I've tried the below solutions already.   But nothing worked out well.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/791611/vmware-kernel-module-error  https://askubuntu.com/questions/812552/vmware-workstation-pro-12-on-ubuntu-16-04-cannot-compile-vmmon     https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7841306.html#7841306    https://askubuntu.com/questions/767791/vmware-virtual-machine-monitor-failed-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Answer (score 0):

woahh!!

VMware application started working fine after uninstalling earlier version (VMware-Workstation-Full-12.1.0-3272444.x86_64) with out keeping configs, Then installing Workstation 12 pro.

Comment: VMware 12 pro is nothing but version 12.5.2 build-4638234